# How to reflect the library installed to Google Cloud VM using SSH for all user accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04

I am very much new to Google Cloud and Ubuntu. I have created an instance of Google Cloud Computing Engine VM. The instance is a Ubuntu 18.04LTS machine. By connecting through SSH in the GC computing instances page, I have installed some libraries into the VM instance. For example let's assume that I have installed **brew** in Ubuntu.

[image]

Now, if I log into the VM instance as root using **Microsoft Remote Desktop** software and search for brew, I see that brew is not installed.

[image]

However, if I create a directory or a file from SSH, I can see that directory/file in the instance through my root account as well. What am I missing here? Why the installed packages do not remain through out all the accounts?

Comment: You are logging in as different users. The first is a normal user, the second is a root user.

Comment: How can I install as one user so that root user gets those packages installed while logging into the machine?